# Is there a way to get height info of any geometry in geometry node editor?

Tags: node-editor, procedural, geometry-nodes

Is there a way to get height info of any geometry in geometry node editor?

For example, here I am using a 'Object Info' node to get a geometry. I want to get the height of that object.

[image: Object Info Node]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. Probably two most reasonable options are:

- Difference of Bounding Box minimum and maximum, separating out Z component
- Statistical range of Z component of position for all vertices

Below I use both techniques to control cube dimensions based on the targeted object's height:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I apologize for the necropost, but I modified [Markus von Broady](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/60486/markus-von-broady)'s bounding box solution because for some reason scale didn't apply to the dimensions when I tried this. My nodes for the bounding box method will get the X, Y, and Z scales of the geometry. The separate XYZ node at the end isn't required, it'll work as just the vector; I just put it there because it suited my needs for one of my projects.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. There is another cleaner approach with Attribute Statistic Node. You can get the range of Z position of the points in the geometry.